# In snowflake , while granting 'usage' access on a stored procedure I am encountering with syntax error

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, privileges

Grant usage on procedure_testing(varchar) to role analyst;

Error message :

SQL Compilation error : syntax error line 1 at position 33 unexpected '('.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be missing a word stating the object before the name (procedure in this case), hence the syntax error.  Perhaps this?

grant usage on procedure procedure_testing(varchar) to role analyst;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the message is misleading. Some hints may be:

1. You are accidentally granting with a role that doesn't have the privilege to do so.
2. Is it really a procedure? Maybe it's an UDF. Then you need "GRANT USAGE ON FUNCTION procedure_testing(varchar) to role analyst"
3. Add the word "procedure" before the procedure name